# How do I display popup only once per session?

Tags: android, session

I want to show alert only once per session.
 I am calling this method in onCreateView, but I want to show this only once

```
 private void ShowDialog() {

    new SweetAlertDialog(getContext())
            .setTitleText("Attention!")
            .setContentText("Have You Checked Followup list? Check Here !!")
            .setConfirmText("Followup List")
            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                       ShowFollowupList();
                    sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();

                }
            })
            .setCancelButton("Cancel", new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                    sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

Comment: is there any codition for popup ? something like if user is new or ?

Comment: You can store this in sharedPref if the dialog is shown or not .

Comment: no , only when he is logged in pop needs to display once

Comment: private boolean isFirstTime() {

        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
        if (!ranBefore) {
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
            editor.commit();
        }
        return !ranBefore;
    }


using this code i am able to show only first time of installation

Comment: your user stays login permanently or logout after app closed ?

Answer (score 0):

Store a value in your sharedPref , once you loggedin :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

editor.putBoolean("DialogShow", false);
 editor.apply();

Now in your onCreate , check if the this value is false or not .

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getBoolean("DialogShow", false);
if (restoredText) {
 showDialog();
 //Now change the value of the above sharedPref to true . and dont forget to 
 commit the change in shared Pref
}
```

The time you logout from your application , clear the data from sharedPref.